# How to create an alternate title for a node when in a nodequeue?

Tags: blocks, 7, nodes

We want to be able to override the title of certain content items, but only temporarily, while they're included in a nodequeue. For example, we have a nodequeue view block in a small "featured" sidebar, without much room for long titles.

I want to avoid adding an alternate title to each content type because there are lots of content types and the alternate title only needs to be used while the node is in the nodequeue (ie, featured). Once the node gets replaced in the nodequeue, the alternate title would be cluttering up the database.

I found a module called [Nodequeue Annotate](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue_annotate), that happens to have the data structure I needed but it's intended for an unrelated use case. I've written a companion module to make it do what I need, but it seems like a bit of a hack to piggyback on a module to make it solve an unrelated use case.

So, I'm curious how would others handle that use case?

Answer (score 2):

I've used this css quite often in these cases:

```
width: // short width;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Which turns something like

```
A great new article about something so important that we have highlighted it for you
```

into

```
A great new article about som...
```

Obviously, this works best when the jist of the title is in the beginning of it :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Shortening the titles is just one example though. They'd also like to be able to do things like include calls to action in some of the titles.